# How to render slightly difference partial in "index" page and "show" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

There is a model `Company` that has many `DailyDatum`.

I want to show the daily data in `companies/:id/daily_data` and `daily_data/index`. But in the company's page I don't want to show `company.name` column.

#### views/daily_data/_daily_datum.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <td><%= daily_datum.company.name %></td>
  # This company.name needs to be shown when the partial is called from daily data index.
  <td><%= daily_datum.column1 %></td>
  <td><%= daily_datum.column2 %></td>
</tr>
```

#### views/daily_data/index.html.erb

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company Name</th>
    <th>Daily Datum1</th>
    <th>Daily Datum2</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <%= render @daily_data %>
</table>
```

#### views/companies/daily_data.html.erb

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <!--<th>Company Name</th>-->
    <th>Daily Datum1</th>
    <th>Daily Datum2</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <%= render @daily_data %>
</table>
```

How should I handle situation like this? Does I need to create another partial HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be overkill since you're only trying to conditionally render one single field, but the "**right**" approach would be to create a helper.

I'd recommend creating a helper to conditionally render one of two partials for `@daily_data` depending on the `path`.

companies_helper.rb

```
def is_companies_index_path?
  current_page?(companies_index_url)
end

def is_companies_show_path?
  current_page?(companies_show_url)
end

def render_appropriate_partial
  render 'daily_data_a' if is_companies_index_path?
  render 'daily_data_b' if is_companies_show_path?
end
```

Then in your views you can simply call:

```
<% render_appropriate_partial %>
```

And it will render the appropriate partial based on which route/url your on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Routing Paramters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters) to know what is the current action/controller, so with an if condition you can add the company name or not.

```
<% if action_name == 'index' && controller_name == 'daily_data' %>
  <th>Company Name</th>
<% end %>
```

Comment: we're advocating the same idea, except my answer looks at your defined routes instead of having to manually set `action_name` & `controller_name`. Would still work, mine is just slightly more reusable :)